# WP8 ListBox DataTemplate Throws Exception When StackPanel Width is Full-Width

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

The exact XAML code is as below :

```
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Margin="6,6,6,6"
                        Background="Gray"
                        Orientation="Vertical"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        Width="*">
                        ...
```

Other Width values runs perfect.

Comment: If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This will help future readers to find what they need (and trust it) and will help to keep the focus on older questions which still don't have answers ;)

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.frameworkelement.width%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) :

> The width of the object, in pixels. The default is Double.NaN. Except
>   for the special Double.NaN value, this value must be equal to or
>   greater than 0. See Remarks for upper bound information

It cannot take `*` as value.
The only special value it can take is `Double.NaN` (to represent the Auto behaviour) :

> The default value of Height and Width is not 0; it is Double.NaN.
>   Height and Width support the ability to be an unset "Auto" value.
>   Because Height and Width are double values, Double.NaN is used as a
>   special value to represent this "Auto" behavior. The layout system
>   interprets the "Auto" value to generally mean that the object should
>   be sized to the available size in layout, instead of to a specific
>   pixel value.

Maybe you are mixing the StackPanel [Width](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.frameworkelement.width%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) property with the [one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.controls.columndefinition.width%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) dedicated to [Grid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.controls.grid%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)'s [ColumnDefinition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.controls.columndefinition%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) , which is not a `double` but a `GridLength` type.

If you want your `StackPanel` to take all the remaning space in width then you have to put it inside a `Grid` :

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <StackPanel Margin="6,6,6,6"
              Background="Gray"
              Orientation="Vertical"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left">
  ...
</Grid>
```

OR

You can also try to simply set the [StackPanel.HorizontalAlignement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.horizontalalignment%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) property to the `Stretch` value.

If none of these proposal work, then the problem is located inside the `ListBoxItem` or `ListBox` default template.